# Is there a way to test my Ionic app in iOS mode on my PC?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, browser, ionic4

Since many components in Ionic look different from MD to iOS, is there a way to test the iOS look in-browser on my PC? I'm just looking for a way to test it in development mode, I know that you can't build for iOS from a PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ionic serve --lab`

Run this command in your respective directory it will open a browser interface **Android**,**iOS** and **Desktop Application** as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome DevTools, use the Device Toolbar (second button from left on the 'Elements, Console, Sources...' bar)

Pick any iOS device and refresh the page!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ionic serve -l` while development.

This (can) host the app in all different modes and provides some useful links to the documentation. Sadly sometimes it's a little bit buggy but restarting helps.